# Ethernet Network() device not managed ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, networking, wireless, network-manager, ethernet

Both Ethernet and Wifi Networks are disconnected from about 3 hours before posting this question on my ubuntu 16.04 machine.
Things I tried from reading before posting here:

1. `sudo service network-manager restart` --> not working
2. `sudo touch /etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/10-globally-managed-devices.conf_orig` and `sudo service network-manager restart`--> not working
3. Change managed=true in /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf and restart network-manager --> not working

**I do notice though that for wired in "System Settings > Networks", the cable says unplugged. But I have the cable plugged and that is the first thing I checked. Even if my cable network is down, why Wifi? Is it possible that the physical ethernet port and wifi adapter have gone bad?**
I even tried updating my realtek drivers as given [here](https://unixblogger.com/2016/08/11/how-to-get-your-realtek-rtl8111rtl8168-working-updated-guide/).

Please help me get through this issue. If in case there is anything that I am missing here kindly point it out.

Some details which might be useful :
**nmcli dev**

```
DEVICE    TYPE      STATE         CONNECTION     
docker0   bridge    connected     docker0        
cdc-wdm1  gsm       connected     Airtel Default 
wlp2s0    wifi      disconnected  --             
enp1s0    ethernet  unavailable   --             
vmnet1    ethernet  unmanaged     --             
vmnet8    ethernet  unmanaged     --             
lo        loopback  unmanaged     --
```

**cat /etc/network/interfaces**

```
# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
```

[Network Manager GUI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iJSHU.png)

**sudo lshw -c net**

```
  *-network               
   description: Ethernet interface
   product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
   vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
   logical name: enp1s0
   version: 07
   serial: 74:86:7a:72:14:d2
   size: 100Mbit/s
   capacity: 1Gbit/s
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
   configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8168 driverversion=8.041.00-NAPI duplex=half latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=100Mbit/s
   resources: irq:25 ioport:3000(size=256) memory:c2404000-c2404fff memory:c2400000-c2403fff
*-network
   description: Wireless interface
   product: BCM43142 802.11b/g/n
   vendor: Broadcom Corporation
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
   logical name: wlp2s0
   version: 01
   serial: 9c:2a:70:bb:35:03
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
   configuration: broadcast=yes driver=wl0 driverversion=6.30.223.271 (r587334) latency=0 multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11abg
   resources: irq:17 memory:c2500000-c2507fff
*-network
   description: Ethernet interface
   physical id: 2
   logical name: wwp0s20u2i3
   serial: 86:3a:2a:87:fd:5f
   capabilities: ethernet physical
   configuration: broadcast=yes driver=qmi_wwan driverversion=22-Aug-2005 firmware=WWAN/QMI device ip=100.89.254.112 link=yes multicast=yes
```

**sudo ifconfig** output:

```
  enp1s0    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 74:86:7a:72:14:d2  
      UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
      RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
      Interrupt:25 Base address:0x4000 

  lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
      inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
      inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
      UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
      RX packets:45733 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:45733 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1 
      RX bytes:26725902 (26.7 MB)  TX bytes:26725902 (26.7 MB)

  vmnet1    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:50:56:c0:00:01  
      inet addr:172.16.64.1  Bcast:172.16.64.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
      inet6 addr: fe80::250:56ff:fec0:1/64 Scope:Link
      UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:1376 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
      RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

  vmnet8    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:50:56:c0:00:08  
      inet addr:172.16.161.1  Bcast:172.16.161.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
      inet6 addr: fe80::250:56ff:fec0:8/64 Scope:Link
      UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:1376 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
      RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

  wlp2s0    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 9c:2a:70:bb:35:03  
      UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:388
      TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
      RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
      Interrupt:17 

  wwp0s20u2i3 Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 86:3a:2a:87:fd:5f  
      inet addr:100.89.254.112  Bcast:100.89.254.115  Mask:255.255.255.252
      UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:23212 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:24048 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
      RX bytes:14332307 (14.3 MB)  TX bytes:3278231 (3.2 MB)
```

**lspci**

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation 3rd Gen Core processor DRAM Controller (rev 09)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller (rev 09)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family USB xHCI Host Controller (rev 04)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family MEI Controller #1 (rev 04)
00:1a.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #2 (rev 04)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family High Definition Audio Controller (rev 04)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 1 (rev c4)
00:1c.1 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 2 (rev c4)
00:1c.2 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 3 (rev c4)
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #1 (rev 04)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation HM77 Express Chipset LPC Controller (rev 04)
00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series Chipset Family 6-port SATA Controller [AHCI mode] (rev 04)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family SMBus Controller (rev 04)
01:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 07)
02:00.0 Network controller: Broadcom Corporation BCM43142 802.11b/g/n (rev 01)
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `cat /etc/network/interfaces` terminal command.

Comment: Done. Had added them previously too :)

Comment: So post `sudo ifconfig`output. You have a docker bridge. [It has to be well configured](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/networking/default_network/custom-docker0/) or you will not get a suitable connection.

Comment: Coincidentally I did purge dockers as I am no longer using it. Hence took the liberty to `ip link delete docker0` and also `nmcli connection delete docker0`.  Output of `sudo ifconfig` in the question now. Please take a look.

Comment: @Pilot6 : Please let me know if you need any more information. I am right now stuck and quite literally unable to proceed anywhere with this issue.. Would really help if I can get any lead..