# Ethernet Network button not showing

Tags: networking, drivers, ethernet

When I first open Ubuntu on my visual machine system,
“Ethernet network” button was turned to gray, I can not find anything about wireless network information, but I can link wired network automatically.

Besides, I also can not find anything about additional drivers.

[image]

Does anyone know why ? thank you !

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/964668/ethernet-network-device-not-managed-ubuntu-16-04     i encountered the similar question with this friend. i also did what he did.,but still couldn't get through this question

Comment: there are solutions depending on your ubuntu version ... start nm applet with dbus or  reconfigure ndicator-applet ... please see this thread : https://askubuntu.com/questions/507310/network-manager-icon-disappeared-14-04