# My wired connection does not work. What information is needed to diagnose the issue?

Tags: networking, drivers, network-manager, internet, ethernet

I wish to build a question that would fix the information gathering problem for wired issues.
This is just like [my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-information-is-needed-to-diagnos](https://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-information-is-needed-to-diagnos). Hopefully one can then build up a script that eases the headaches for wired connections too.

This would make the following questions more systematic

- [Wired connection unmanaged - ubuntu 18.04 (common solution does not work)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1272474/wired-connection-unmanaged-ubuntu-18-04-common-solution-does-not-work)
- [Ubuntu 18.04 Ethernet not managed](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1115117/ubuntu-18-04-ethernet-not-managed)
- [Ethernet device not managed](https://askubuntu.com/questions/882806/ethernet-device-not-managed)
- [Ethernet Network() device not managed ubuntu 16.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/964668/ethernet-network-device-not-managed-ubuntu-16-04)

Comment: I do not see an actual question here.

Comment: we already have the question you linked to - what makes this different? Couldn't you just add your answer there?

Answer (score 0):

Currently, these are the ones that I can think about.

- sudo lshw -C network
- ip link show
- ip addr show